# How to implement mutli-tenant login with Facebook, Twitter, Google+, etc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, facebook-login, multi-tenant, social-media

I want to allow users of a SaaS based, asp.net MVC, Multi-tenant DB to login using their social media credentials (FB, TW, G+, etc).

In addition to the social media account validation, how can we determine which tenant or users within a tenant in the DB to validate against?  I presume some flavor of Asp.Net Identity should be used to bridge the gap??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a custom OAuth server that inturn handles the pluggability of the various social media login modes via OWIN middlewares.

However, when you wanted to have a simplified approach, you can choose to go with `Windows Azure` Access Control service which can enable you to identify the tenant via their URI.

In that case, you can infer the tenant name or tenant unique value from the URI [like a subdomain part] of the URI.Host.

You may refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn486924.aspx) / [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446534.aspx) / [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/03/provisioning-a-windows-azure-active-directory-tenant-as-an-identity-provider-in-an-acs-namespacenow-point-click/).

In case you wanted to build your own model, you will have to capture the tenant information via either a unique URI from where the tenant comes from or from getting a tenant unique value from the UI or as a query string from a URI [Rare & least secure case].

The points worth pondering upon will be

1. Time
2. Cost [Azure does not come for free]
3. Customization aspects

Please share your thoughts on the points above.